# duvida sobre ação css em div

Tags: html, css

Bom galera eu gostaria de saber como posso fazer uma div acionar o display none
quando eu estiver com focus na input ex de codigo

```
//CSS
.email:focus > div.oculta{
     display:none;
}
//HTML
<div class="form">
  <input type="text" class="email" name="email" placeholder="email" />
</div>

<div class="oculta">
<!-- Isso Aqui terá que ficar display none a partir do focus na input form  -->
teste
</div>
```

como posso fazer isso funcionar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu seletor CSS está aplicando `display: none` para um `div.oculta` **filho** de um `.email:focus`. No seu HTML, o `div.oculta` não será afetado, pois não é filho de `.email:focus`.

Dessa forma, você poderia fazer funcionar: utilizando o seletor `~` ou `+`, que selecionam elementos seguidos:

```
.email:focus + div.oculta{
     display:none;
}

<div class="form">
  <input type="text" class="email" name="asdasd" placeholder="email" />
  <div class="oculta">
    teste
  </div>
</div>
```

Caso você queira ocultar o `div.oculta` com o HTML dessa forma, não será possível usar seletores CSS para atingí-la a partir de `.email:focus`. Portanto, vai precisar de um evento JavaScript `onFocus` ligado ao elemento. Por exemplo:

```
document.querySelector('.email').onfocus = function() {
    document.querySelector('.oculta').style.display = "none";
}

document.querySelector('.email').onfocusout = function() {
    document.querySelector('.oculta').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Poxa amigo, muitíssimo obrigado. agora compreendo. Sim realmente funciona com o js. agradeço